# AJAX and playing a sound once

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash

Alright, so here's the issue. We have a website which displays status updates throughout our various facilities (they all have LCDs with a fullscreen IE page I point it to). Right now I go to my management page with a WYSIWYG-editor, type in the messages/updates, which saves it to a .txt file (alert.txt) and it updates the page on the screens via AJAX. The page on the screens checks for updates at a set interval of 5 seconds.

What I want to do now is play a sound to alert when an update is given (the screen only displays critical network errors and such)

I use

```
<body onload="window.setTimeout('loadXMLDoc()',1000);">
```

which calls to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  document.getElementById("changes").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","alerts.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

I've tried adding the sound clip via an embed HTML code (created a Flash object that plays it once upon loading the Flash object) to the text file, but this causes it to play once every iteration. Even if there are no changes.

Halp?

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery and PHP ?

Comment: The text file is edited through PHP, the Jquery was a mistake. But did you come here just to be a tag-nazi or to answer the question?

Comment: I came here to try and answer a jQuery question ... but seen as your so polite I will add my answer ....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the flash into the `alerts.txt` create a new DOM object once the `changes` div has been updated :

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  document.getElementById("changes").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  // Add Flash object to DOM
   var emb = document.createElement("embed");
   emb.setAttribute("type","application/x-shockwave-flash");   
   emb.setAttribute("autostart","true"); 
   emb.setAttribute("data","<your url>");
  }
}
```

You will need to change the URL to match the URL of your sound flash file and add any attributes you need to set

There is a problem with this approach in that the object will get created each time .... so perhaps you could change remove the element first then re-add it.

Also check out this answer -> [Playing dynamically embedded sound object via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909117/playing-dynamically-embedded-sound-object-via-javascript)